# Menu contribution with icon and text

Tags: eclipse, plugins, swt

It is possible to create a menu item in eclipse with an icon and a text? Normally all menu items on the main menu are displayed with an icon only. I need, however, to display a short text next to the icon.

E.g. in the attached screenshot the "R2" short text next to the "run" icon (I don't want to enhance the "run" menu, this is just an example).

[image: Menu with icon and text]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a command contributed through `org.eclipse.ui.menus` you can add the mode attribute.  See the Extension Point Description (you can get to that from the *PDE Editor>Extensions* tab).

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.workbench.file">
     <command commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy"
              mode="FORCE_TEXT"/>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: This worked fine, thanks. Do you know how to set the label in a dynamic/programmatic way? I currently set the "R2" label in the plugin.xml, what I finally need is setting it based on current config.

Comment: Your handler must implement `org.eclipse.ui.commands.IElementUpdater`.  Calls to `org.eclipse.ui.commands.ICommandService.refreshElements(String, Map)` will allow you to update the UIElement with text.

Comment: sorry for the beginner question: which class is the handler and how/where do I set it?

Comment: I'd start with http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework.  Also look at the extension points org.eclipse.ui.commands, org.eclipse.ui.handlers, and org.eclipse.ui.menus in http://help.eclipse.org *> Platform Plug-in Developer Guide*